# Mac osx でユーザが起動するアプリを抑制したい。

Tags: objective-c, macos

Xcode Objective-Cで開発しています。
Mac OS X で、ユーザが起動指示したアプリの中で、
特定のアプリだけを起動できないように抑制したいです。
さらに、その場合、このアプリは起動が禁止されていますと
メッセージを通知したいです。
ご存知の方がいらしゃいましたら、ご教示ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 説明不足ですいません。ユーザが起動指示とは、Finder上などで、普通にユーザがアプリを起動しようとする操作のことを指しています。Mac上で実現可能な方法を探しています。助けてもらえないでしょうか？

Comment: Unixのgroup実行権限で、特定のグループに属している人にだけ実行権限を与えれば良い気がします。ただ⌘Iで表示される権限では実行権限はいじれないようですので、ターミナルから実行する必要がありそうです。

Answer (score 2):

ペアレンタルコントロールではダメなのでしょうか？
[システム環境設定] - [ペアレンタルコントロール]でアカウント毎に設定できます。

Comment: プログラムで動的に制御を行いたいのですが、難しいでしょうか？